# MySQL репликация на три мастера

Tags: mysql, linux, mariadb, репликация

Есть три сервера в разных местах. Хотелось бы пользоваться каждым локально.

Настроил автоинкремент через 3, первый прописал мастером на втором, второй мастером на первом - они синхронизируются в обе стороны.

Третий сейчас работает просто как резервное копирование. Прописал ему мастера на первый сервер, но не нахожу параметра как задать второго мастера, чтоб данные с третьего пересылать на первый и второй.

Соединить кольцом вроде можно, но тогда при выключении одного не будут синхронизироваться остальные.

Можно ли в MySQL\MariaDB сделать full-mesh или звезду с двухсторонним обменом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из того что перечитал я понял следующее:

MySQL умеет оперировать только единственным мастером. Звезды или меша не выйдет даже в кластере.

Возможно есть какое-то расширение\плагин для правильной репликации. Ответы приветствуются.